# Get the Gmail profile picture of a logged in user

Tags: gmail, google-contacts-api

It is posible to get the Gmail profile picture of a logged-in user, using any of the Google apis?

Using the Google contacts api I was able get my contacts pictures, but not mine. Using the Google Plus api I could retrieve my Google plus picture, which is different from my Gmail picture.

Comment: Come on, folks. If you're voting down, leave a comment saying why. If your vote is meant to say, "This is a lousy question," remember that constructive feedback is how you get better ones.

Comment: How can i improve my question?

Comment: Did you finnaly got it to work? I'm looking for the same thing... thank you!

Comment: @Lucia Not yet. The proyect was finished a long ago, so i'm not actively investigating the issue in the present time

Answer (score 0):

Use User Profile Information, make an authorized request to GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token={accessToken}
See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login for more details